# Numpy not finding temp file

Tags: python, numpy, temporary-files

I am running a python CGI script using numpy to read data from a CSV that is created on the fly.  Numpy is complaining that it cannot find the file, yet it is there.  From the python script I can use system(cat) to print the file beforehand...

```
filename is: /tmp/file3aQJRn
Dump file with system(cat)...
A
-257
-1
-136
29567
-97
-8867
-27041
-12323
-17473
-659
Ask numpy to read it...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  (some lines deleted, then...)
  File "request", line 195, in get_rawcsv_column
    col_data = get_csv_column(fname,column)
  File "request", line 189, in get_csv_column
    all_data = np.genfromtxt(fname,delimiter=",")
  File "usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1551, in genfromtxt
  File "usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 151, in open
  File "usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 501, in open
OSError: "/tmp/file3aQJRn" not found.
```

Afterward, I can dump the file at the bash prompt:

```
# cat /tmp/file3aQJRn
A
-257
-1
-136
29567
-97
-8867
-27041
-12323
-17473
-659
```

And I can invoke Python (3.6) and numpy to read the file...

```
numpy.genfromtxt("/tmp/file3aQJRn",delimiter=",")
array([             nan,  -2.57000000e+02,  -1.00000000e+00,
        -1.36000000e+02,   2.95670000e+04,  -9.70000000e+01,
        -8.86700000e+03,  -2.70410000e+04,  -1.23230000e+04,
        -1.74730000e+04,  -6.59000000e+02])
```

(The nan is not a problem.  It's a column header that is subsequently removed from the array.)

What's going on here?  The temp file is generated by a C++ application using std::ofstream having gotten a temporary filename from tmpnam().

Comment: I would replace, or preface, the first `genfromtxt` with a Python `os` file operation - directory listing, open, or what ever.  I don't think this is a `numpy` issue.  For one reason or other, the file is not where you expect to see it when you try to read it.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/_datasource.py#L610

This looks to be the where numpy is trying to find the file (your version appears to be different though). There is a warning before that line specifying that its `_findfile(path)` method will fail on a file opened for writing. I would make sure that your C++ application does not have the file open while you're trying to read it.

Comment: The C++ code uses try block that starts by instantiating an std::ofstream as an automatic, and ends with that file being closed and destroyed by falling out of scope.  In the parent function of that code, the filename is sent to the python script, so there isn't anything obvious going wrong with respect to the file remaining open for write.

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid coding error.  The filename numpy was given actually had quotes around it!